# MongoDB Text Search logic

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

What to tweak on MongoDB text search if I want this below

```
var items = [{
  title: 'Fender Jazz Bass Guitar 4 String Barely used'
}, {
  title: 'Mark Bass'
}, {
  title: 'Fender Telecaster'
}, {
  title: 'Fender Double Fat Strat'
}];

db.collection('items').createIndex({ title: 'text'}, function(){});

// Using MongooseJS to query
Items.find({ $text: { $search: 'Fender Jazz Bass Guitar 4 String' }})

// After query this it does not return Fender Jazz Bass Guitar 4 String as the top most search result
```

I want the array of results first element to be the `Fender Jazz Bass Guitar 4 String Barely used`

Is this even possible? or do I have to another more sophisticated search engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text search, by default, does not return the matching documents in order of matching scores, see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/text-search-with-rlp/). You need to use the `$meta` expression in the $sort stage to sort by `textScore`.

```
 Item.find({ $text: { $search: 'Fender Jazz Bass Guitar 4 String' }}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
```

After sorting, the document containing `Fender Jazz Bass Guitar 4 String Barely used` should appear as the first element in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using Text search in Mongo can either search for words (in your case search is for any text indexed field containing 'Fender' OR 'Jazz' OR 'Bass' OR 'Guitar' OR '4 ' OR 'String')

If you want specifically the phrase to appear only, use the phrase convention of escaped strings

```
{ $text: { $search: "\"Fender Jazz Bass Guitar 4 String\"" } }
```

**Phrases**
To match on a phrase, as opposed to individual terms, enclose the phrase in escaped double quotes (\")

If the phrase search option isn't what you're looking for then I am not aware of an easy way to accomplish what you are seeking. Can find more information on structuring search phrases [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

*Edited to link to MongoDB docs and clarify Phrases

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is sorting the results on the basis of their relevance to your keywords.For this purpose,mongodb text search generates meta score.Meta score is the weighted average score of a document according to keywords entered.You can then sort the results on this meta score.

This can be done as:

```
db.yourcollectioname.find({ $text: { $search:"keywords" } },
{ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
```

To know all the steps you need to follow to successfully run a mongodb text search query,refer to this article:http://codewhoop.com/article/MongoDb%20Text%20Search%20in%20fields%20of%20document

I found this article very useful.Hopefully you too find it useful :)